# AngularJS: Access DOM elements of directive in its controller

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am writing an image carousel directive without any other libraries than the base AngularJS.

```
simpleCarousel.$inject = [];

function simpleCarousel() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'someurl.html',
        scope: {
            // Scope variables
        },
        controller: simpleCarouselController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true
    };
    simpleCarouselController.$inject = [];
    function simpleCarouselController() {
        angular.extend(this, {
            next : //handle next image sliding
            prev : //handle previous image sliding
        });
        function detectSwipe(el) {
            var touchsurface = el, 
                swipeDirection, 
                startX,
                distX,
                threshold = 150,
                allowedTime = 2000,
                elapsedTime,
                startTime;

            touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
                var touchObject = e.changedTouches[0];
                swipeDirection = 'none';
                distX = 0;
                startX = touchObject.pageX;
                startTime = new Date().getTime();
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
            touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
            touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
                var touchObject = e.changedTouches[0];
                distX = touchObject.pageX - startX;
                elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
                if (distX > 0) {
                    swipeDirection = 'right';
                    return swipeDirection;
                } else if (distX < 0) {
                    swipeDirection = 'left';
                    return swipeDirection;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the event handler for touch events. But how can I pass the element to the touch event?
Also, should I use JS to handle preventing user click while sliding or CSS user-select property?

Comment: You could use ```link``` function of directive where you have as argument the element that this directive matches

Comment: @Dario, can we declare link function and a controller as well for the directive?

Comment: Yes sure, one directive can have compile, link and controller functions. Link function is the one where you should modify the DOM and attach event listeners.

Answer (score -1):

It is usually considered as a bad practice and discouraged to attach event handlers in controller.

Also, you might want to checkout ngTouch to detect swiping.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch